# VBA Pivot Table Collapse all fields

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I've created a pivot table in VBA full of string data, but can't seem to collapse all the fields in the pivot table, how would I do this?
Here's my source code

```
    SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(46, 3)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
StartPvt = Sheets("Key Controls").Cells(2, 5).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")
pvt.PivotFields("SOP Reference").Orientation = xlRowField
pvt.PivotFields("Key Control ID").Orientation = xlRowField
pvt.PivotFields("Key Control Name").Orientation = xlRowField
```

Comment: Orientation of row fields should have positions also. Ex. ` With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Key Control ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With` Suppose you want to collapse entire field to "SOP Reference" Selecting a proper cell say `A15`code will be `  Range("A15").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Key Control Name"). _
        PivotItems("electron").DrillTo "SOP Reference"` Does your table [look like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/51znhaab1z0lnno/pivot_q070716.xlsm?dl=0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do **NOT** use `pf.ShowDetail = False` :

It is a nightmare of efficiency, you'll get stuck for a LONG moment and probably crash Excel!

---

**The good method to use is `DrillTo` :**

```
Public Sub PivotTable_Collapse()

    Dim pT As PivotTable
    Dim pF As PivotField

    Set pT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    With pT
        For Each pF In pT.RowFields
            pF.DrillTo pF.Name
        Next pF
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear, you can do the same thing with the column fields, just change `For Each pF In pT.RowFields` to `For Each pF In pT.ColumnFields`