# How can I collapse or expand a pivot table in python using win32com

Tags: python, excel, pivot, win32com

I'm creating a pivot table using the win32com.client module.
I'm managing to create it exactly as I want,
but the finishing touches that I need is to collapse the entire pivot table.

any suggestions?

This is my Code:

```
**
def insert_pt_field_set(pt):
    field_rows = {}
    field_rows['Period'] = pt.PivotFields('Period')
    field_rows['Name'] = pt.PivotFields('Name')

    field_values = {}
    field_values['Name'] = pt.PivotFields("Name")

    field_rows['Period'].Orientation = 1
    field_rows['Period'].Position = 1

    field_rows['Name'].Orientation = 1
    field_rows['Name'].Position = 2


    field_values['Name'].Orientation = 4
    field_values['Name'].Function = -4112


xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlApp.Visible = True
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('output.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws_pivot = wb.Worksheets('Pivot_Sheet1')

pt_cache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(1, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
pt = pt_cache.CreatePivotTable(ws_pivot.Range("B3"), "PivotName")

pt.ColumnGrand = True
pt.RowGrand = False

pt.SubtotalLocation(2)
pt.RowAxisLayout(2)

pt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"

# Entering the function that arrange the fields in the pivot table
insert_pt_field_set(pt)
wb.Close(True)
```

**

Answer (score 1):

Working in Excel 365

If you need to roll over the field:

```
ws.PivotTables("PivotName").PivotFields("SomeFiled").DrillTo("SomeFiled")
```

Or

```
ws.PivotTables("PivotName").PivotFields("SomeFiled").ShowDetail = False
```

If you just want to hide the fields:

```
ws.Columns('A:B').OutlineLevel = 2
ws.Columns('A:B').EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Similar question
[VBA Pivot Table Collapse all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246393/vba-pivot-table-collapse-all-fields)

It says it's better to use "DrillTo". maybe

More information here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.drillto